# jQuery write JSON item value to each respective td with an id

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I have a JSON array gathered from an AJAX response, as such `[{"a":"dog","b":2,"c":3}, {"a":"cat","b":90,"c":4}]`. I also have an HTML table as such:

```
<table id="reportTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>b</th>
          <th>c</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td id="aValue"></td>
          <td id="bValue"></td>
          <td id="cValue"></td>
      <tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to write the values of each JSON item to each `<td>` using the ID of each `<td>` tag, using jQuery. I have gotten the following so far, however I am now stuck and still cannot render anything inside the table:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form[name='table-update-form']").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.getJSON("/AJAX_response", formData, function (data) {

            var response = data.result;

            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                $("#aValue").html(item.a);
                $("#bValue").html(item.b);
                $("#cValue").html(item.c);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: "_still cannot render anything inside the table_" If it doesn't render anything at all, you might have some issues with your AJAX request. Check your browser's console for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that there are some issues with your HTML. The `th` need closing tags, but the main issue is that you've set `id` attributes on the `td` cells which implies that these can only exist once in the DOM.

To iterate through your array of objects you will need to create multiple new rows. As such I would suggest you create a hidden 'template' row in the `tfoot` of the table which is cloned for each object in your array. From there you can place `data` attributes on the cells to be used to match the cell to the property of each object so that the value can be injected in to it.

With that said, try this:

```js
// In the AJAX callback...
var response = [{"a":"dog","b":2,"c":3}, {"a":"cat","b":90,"c":4}]

let rows = response.map(obj => {
  let $tr = $('tfoot tr').clone();  
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => $tr.find(`td[data-key="${key}"]`).text(obj[key]));
  return $tr;
})
$('#reportTable').append(rows);
```

```css
tfoot { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="reportTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td data-key="a"></td>
      <td data-key="b"></td>
      <td data-key="c"></td>
    </tr>  
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I cannot get this to work. Your answer is the most efficient so I am keen on going this route and getting it to work.

Comment: If you can check the console for errors, hopefully there will be something in there I can help you debug

Comment: Yes ofcourse, thanks (let me know if more needed) - desk:457 Uncaught TypeError: response.map is not a function
    at Object.success (desk:457)
    at c (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:3)
    at k (jquery.min.js:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.min.js:5)

Comment: That error means that the `response` variable does not hold an array. Are you sure it's not an unserialised JSON string?

Comment: Okay noted. I will make sure and revert soonest

Comment: Hi Rory, sorry for delay but I checked the type of the AJAX response by printing to console and it indeed comes up as string. Solution works by parsing the response first `$.parseJSON(response);` - silly mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As your response is *JSON Array* so you will have mutliple datas to add inside tr so use class instead of id and then generate tr inside your `each` loop and add that inside your `tbody` of table.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
/*$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form[name='table-update-form']").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.getJSON("/AJAX_response", formData, function(data) {*/

var response = [{
  "a": "dog",
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}, {
  "a": "cat",
  "b": 90,
  "c": 4
}];
var html = "";
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
  //append tr inside html variable with values...
  html += `<tr>
      <td class="aValue">${item.a}</td>
      <td class="bValue">${item.b}</td>
      <td class="cValue">${item.c}</td>
      <tr>`
});
$("#reportTable tbody").html(html) //add final htmls inside tbody

/* });
  });
});*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="reportTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a
      </th>
      <th>b
      </th>
      <th>c </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```